# how to duplicated div in js (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rfut.png)

help me please

I need to clone this div, to create a Enigma machine

Comment: have you looked at `Node.cloneNode()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cloneNode(boolean):

```
var item = document.getElementById("id");

var clone = item.cloneNode(true);
```

The boolean value is defined so:

- true: clone item with attributes, values and childs
- false: clone item with attributes and values

Then you can append or insert the element wherever you want, maybe into another div:

```
  document.getElementById("anotherId").appendChild(clone);
```

More information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp)